# How do I scroll a sub element using Webdriver and javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to scroll the subscriptions list of my personal YouTube page, how do I do this? I have written code that allows me to scroll the main page, any ideas as to how the code could be tweaked to scroll the "My subscriptions" section of the YouTube page that appears when signed into YouTube?

```
package Check;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class java {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Sign in')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        driver.findElementById("Email").sendKeys("<My username>");
        driver.findElementById("Passwd").sendKeys("<My password>");
        driver.findElementById("signIn").click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Sign in')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        driver.findElementByCssSelector("div[id='identity-prompt-account-list'] > ul > label + label").click();
        driver.findElementById("identity-prompt-confirm-button").click();
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight," +
        "document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found by a method of trial and error a method that works, by the CSS selector appears to be limited to finding up to the 35th sibling so in the light of this limitation here is the code that I came up with this works very well for what I want to accomplish. Here is my script below:

```
package Check;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class java2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Sign in')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        driver.findElementById("Email").sendKeys("<User name>");
        driver.findElementById("Passwd").sendKeys("<Password>");
        driver.findElementById("signIn").click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElementByCssSelector("div[id='identity-prompt-account-list'] > ul > label + label").click();
        driver.findElementById("identity-prompt-confirm-button").click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        int i =0;
        String CSSText = "ul[id='guide-channels'] > li";
        do {
            if (driver.findElementByCssSelector(CSSText).getText().equals("Josie Outlaw")){
                break;
            }
            CSSText = CSSText + " + li";
            i++;
        } while (i<35);
        js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"vve-check overflowable-list-item guide-channel\")["+i+"].scrollIntoView(false);");
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"vve-check overflowable-list-item guide-channel\")["+i+"].scrollIntoView(true);");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```